# Erlang Select highest bids

Tags: list, dictionary, erlang

In below select_highest_bids function, is it better to use orddict:new() instead of list, something like below ?

```
OrderedBatches = lists:foldl(fun high_bid_filter/2, orddict:new(), Campaigns)
```

How can we change high_bid_filter to return orddict ?

```
select_highest_bids(Campaigns, BidRequest) ->
    lists:map(fun({_, C}) -> C end,
    lists:foldl(fun high_bid_filter/2, [], Campaigns),


high_bid_filter(Campaign = #campaign_response{bid = BR = #bid_response{ad_id = AdID, cpm_bid = Score}}, Campaigns) ->

    case lists:keyfind(AdID, 1, Campaigns) of
        false ->
            [{AdID, Campaign}|Campaigns];
        {AdID, _ = #campaign_response{bid = _ = #bid_response{cpm_bid = EB}}} when EB >= Score ->
            Campaigns;
        {AdID, _ = #campaign_response{bid = _ = #bid_response{cpm_bid = EB}}} when EB < Score ->
            lists:keystore(AdID, 1, Campaigns, {AdID, Campaign})
    end.
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the folder function

```
high_bid_filter(Campaign = #campaign_response{bid = #bid_response{ad_id = AdID, cpm_bid = Score}}, Campaigns) ->
  case orddict:take(AdID, Campaigns) of
    {V, _} when V >= Score -> 
      % find value but higher than Offer
      Campaigns;
    {V, Dict} ->
      % update higher value
      orddict:store(AdID, Campaign, Dict);
    error -> 
      % 
      orddict:store(AdID, Campaign, Campaigns)
  end.
```

i hope it can help you